# How to 'deactivate' active navbar button? (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I remove/overshadow `.ui-btn-active` class on an active button in my navigation bar? When I tap on the button I run a js function and at the end of it I'd like to remove that class or somehow deactivate the button. Setting href to #nonexistent seems to do the trick in desktop browsers but on the mobile ones the button remains active :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something, but have you tried removing the class?

```
$(".ui-btn-active").removeClass('.ui-btn-active');
```

Comment: You're not - it works. Don't know how I missed out `removeClass()` in my research...

Comment: This is not working anymore. Seems that when you removes the class jquery mobile adds it again. Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 13):

Should be

```
$(".ui-btn-active").removeClass('ui-btn-active');
```

`removeClass` accepts a class name without the dot.